# Testing rails controller with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm new to rails and I'm trying to test a controller with rspec. My first test is when the show action is invoked, it should lookup a Category by url.

The problem is when I add the stubbing code, I get the following error:

undefined method `find' for #

my test looks like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe CategoriesController do
    describe "GET /category-name/" do
        before(:each) do
            @category = mock_model(Category)
            Category.stub!(:find).with(:first, :conditions => ["url = :url", {:url => "category-name"}]).and_return(@category)
        end

        it "should find the category by url" do
            controller.show
            Category.should_receive(:find).with(:first, :conditions => ["url = :url", {:url => "category-name"}]).and_return(@category)
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your call to the request should be after any `should_receive`. It's a tense thing. So it kind of reads like this, "Category should receive something, when *this happens*".  "This happens" refers to the request.

```
it "should find the category by url" do
  Category.should_receive(:find).with... 
  get "show", { your params, if you're sending some in }
end
```

Also, you want to go the way of a request vs calling the controller method itself, for this particular test at least.

So

```
post   "action_name"
get    "action_name"
update "action_name"
delete "action_name"
```

instead of

```
controller.action_name
```

Comment: ah, great, thanks. Now the stubbing works correctly but if i try using get "show" i get an error saying:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"categories"}

but rake routes returns:
root  /     {:controller=>"categories", :action=>"index"}
      /:url {:controller=>"categories", :action=>"show"}

Comment: nevermind, I've worked it out. I needed to pass :url to get :show that is why it didn't find my route. Thanks for your help